# ATTINY 1616 WATCHDOG RESET

Tags: avr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTUCP.jpg) Actually i am trying to configure a watchdog timer reset using attiny 1616 but the register configure is too complex for me to understand.

if any one can help me to find any solution, it would be highly appreciable.

this is how i configured watchdog timer but how i do reset it by software.Do i have to add **avr/wdt.h** lib or i there any other way to do, I am willing to know that is it possible to use **Isr of wdt_vect**. I didn't find any article from datasheet relating to the ISR vect of watchdog.

Comment: Configure it by fuses and you don't have to use _PROTECTED_WRITE (from xmega header) to enable it.

Comment: Or even avr/wdt.h + wdt_enable(WDTO_8S) and  wdt_reset();

Comment: But how will i get **watchdog interrupt**. I have gone through the datasheet and there is nothing relating to watchdog timer interrupt, and by fuses i only can active the watchdog bit i think.. Can you give me a hint like example..

Comment: I didn't see anything about ISR, so it's not possible anymore in same manner as in classic AVRs. But you can use RTC PIT (periodic interrupt timer)

Comment: I will be thankful if you can elaborate it in such a way to understand for a beginner. There are lots of doubt like how do i configure it how this work exactly.

Comment: What are you trying to archieve with it exactly? What should be a result with it?

Comment: I want to save the last state of controller before watchdog system reset will happen, so if some how my controller gets stuck or hanged it will resume to the same line where it resets. In my atmeg88pb it is simple but in attiny , I am unable to achieve it.

Comment: On AT TINY you have to change your approach. It is impossible catch interrupt before  reset from WDT. HW core don't have this functionality like AT MEGA88. But all state is preserved after reset from WDT. All registers and SRAM is not changed. You can check `Reset Flag Register` to distinguish reset source.